# What is the being called here: return _()

Tags: c#

I have come across this code in MoreLinq, in file `Batch.cs` ([link](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs#L96)):

```
return _(); IEnumerable<TResult> _()
```

I read up on discards, but nevertheless I cannot make sense of the above code. When I hover above the first `_` it says: "Variables captured: resultSelector, collection".

- What do the two `_()` represent?
- Since we are doing a `return _();`, how can the subsequent code `IEnumerable<TResult> _()` still be executed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `_()` here is a call to the [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) called `_`. Unusual, but valid.

A local function is broadly like a regular method, except that it can only be called *by name* (i.e. the usual way you call a method) from inside the method that declares it (as Eric points out in a comment, there are some other ways that it could be called, for example via a delegate passed out from the method), and (unless decorated `static`) it can pick up locals and parameters from the declaring method as state.

In this case, the intent is to perform eager parameter validation.
With validation code in the [iterator block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators), the parameters validation would be deferred until the first `MoveNext()` call. (i.e. it wouldn't complain about `source` being `null` until someone attempts to `foreach` over the data).

Comment: Shouldn't the body always be declared?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Yes, but I imagine the OP didn't quite paste the code exactly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson by opening the source I noticed it is there, the highlight made me blind ahah

Comment: Any pointers on "eager parameter validation"? I am having a hard time finding resources. I read up on iterator blocks, but not seeing the connection clearly.

Comment: @Robotron try this: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/047f7fcfd2755819b8de7c5afaaf3001 ; this difference can make it more obvious where the actual problem lies; if you pass an unvalidated sequence through a few layers before calling `foreach`, the actual point where the wrong thing happened can be hard to track down

Comment: Not a C# programmer, but the fact that the definition of `_` is after the return instruction bugs me, and I can't find a good reference to understand what feature I don't know. Any quick link I can use to understand more? Thanks.

Comment: @bracco23 "local functions"; nothing says they can't be declared after `return`

Comment: @MarcGravell touchè, I was so focused on the definition itself I lost sight of it being of a functiona and not of a variable.

Comment: Minor nit: the characteristic of local functions that make them local is that their *name* is only in scope in the local neighbourhood of the declaration. A local function can be *called* from anywhere, by, say, passing out a delegate to it. Locality is about controlling access to *names*, not to *the thing named*.

Comment: @EricLippert good nit, +1

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<TResult> _() {}` is [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that called in `return _();`