# Why does this code declare a local function only to call it immediately afterwards?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Follow-up question based on [What is the being called here: return _()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926620/what-is-the-being-called-here-return).

What is the point of declaring the local function below?

```cs
return _(); IEnumerable<TResult> _()
{
    var bucket = new TSource[collection.Count];
    collection.CopyTo(bucket, 0);
    yield return resultSelector(bucket);
}
```

Why not just replace the call with the function body?

```cs
var bucket = new TSource[collection.Count];
collection.CopyTo(bucket, 0);
yield return resultSelector(bucket);
```

Comment: as per my earlier comment: compare and contrast here: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/047f7fcfd2755819b8de7c5afaaf3001 - not having the outer method be an iterator block allows a: eager parameter checking, and b: directly return (non-iterator-block) in the various other cases that it happens

Answer (score -2):

The reason for declaring the local function is not apparent at first. Looking further, the encompassing method returns a `IEnumerable<TResult>`. There are two ways to return an `IEnumerable` from a method.

1. Using the `yield return` statement with objects of type `TResult`
2. Using the `return` statement with an object of type `IEnumerable<TResult>`

But, the two statements cannot be mixed throughout a single method, you will always have to use one or the other on all execution paths of a method.

By using a `return` statement earlier in the method, the same statement had to be used throughout the entire method.

Comment: I don't find this explanation compelling.  I can't think of a good reason why you would want to mix these two statements in the same method in the first place, and you haven't provided a code example illustrating the concept.

Comment: As Marc Gravell points out above, the reason is already adequately stated in the original post you linked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A good reason would be: remove code bloat by inlining the local function declaration in the aforementioned code instead of, you know, declaring the local function right before calling it only once.